# Working with PieChartModel in JSF 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-1.2

I am developing an appication for multiple ping testing to different Ips at a time. That is working fine but I have two issues described below

1. I have to display that in the Pie chart format. When I run multiple ping page and get the response back I could see the Pie chart created but not everytime, sometime its blank not even Pie Diagram is created.
2. Now If the Pie chart gets created and suppose in the same session I use another file with set of different Ips and run the MultiplePingTesting page, I could see the same earlier pie diagram with no updates as per the new file. I know its a very silly question but i am not able to get way out of it.

It would be great if someone can help me out.

**Bean Class**

```
 package My_Package;
import java.io.Serializable;
import org.primefaces.model.chart.PieChartModel;
public class ChartBean implements Serializable {
private PieChartModel pieModel;

public ChartBean() {
    createPieModel();
}

public PieChartModel getPieModel() {
    return pieModel;
}

private void createPieModel() {

    pieModel = new PieChartModel();

    pieModel.set("Connected",MultiplePingTesting.i); 
    pieModel.set("Not Connected",MultiplePingTesting.j);
     //MultiplePingTesting is the class which is responsible for multiple ping testing
}
}
```

**XHTML code**

```
<p:pieChart id="sample" value="#{ChartBean.pieModel}" legendPosition="w"
                title="Sample Pie Chart" dataFormat= "Value" style="width:400px;height:300px" />
```

Comment: It is PrimeFaces I can see.

Comment: Yes, Its primeface. Below is the link from where I got this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pieChart.jsf

And one more thing I have to do this in JSF 2.0 and not in 1.2

Comment: Lion or some one, could you please help m eon this.